# Change the data value of a link and fire another function triggered by the new data value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a simple Like/Unlike button but I can't manage to to make it with the Unlike button because the function just won't fire.

Tried with `.data` and `.attr`.

HTML+PHP:

```
<span id="<?php echo $quote_id; ?>_count"><?php echo $likes_count; ?> likes</span>
<br>
<a class="like_button" data-q="<?php echo $quote_id; ?>" data-action="like" href="#">Like</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('.like_button[data-action="like"]').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var q = $(this).attr('data-q');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost/q/functions/l.php',
                    method: 'get',
                    data: {qi: q, a: "1"},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $('#' + q + '_count').text((data.likes) + ' likes');
                        $('.like_button[data-action="like"]').data('action', 'unlike');
                    }
                });
    });


    $('.like_button[data-action="unlike"]').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var q = $(this).attr('data-q');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost/q/functions/l.php',
                    method: 'get',
                    data: {qi: q, a: "0"},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $('#' + q + '_count').text((data.likes) + ' likes');
                        $('.like_button[data-action="unlike"]').data('action', 'like');
                    }
                });
    });


});
```

Comment: could you post relevant html?

Comment: Do you have multiple like link/buttons on the page? If so I presume you only want to update a single occurrence at a time, correct?

Comment: Edited with the HTML. @scunliffe - I only have one button and I want this button to be used for both likes and unlikes depending on the situation (did user like this already?).

Comment: If you add `console.log(...);` statements as the first line in each of the 4 functions can you see which one's are getting called? e.g. does the "like" work, and update the link to say "unlike"... where does it "die/stop"?

Comment: The problem ist, that `$('.like_button[data-action="unlike"]')` returns an empty array, because jQuery doesn't find an element with that specification when it's executed. Therefore `on` does not apply to anything. If you want event handlers to also apply to new or changed elements, you need to use `$(document).on('click', "someSelector", function () { })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need two `onclick` events. Also, cache `$(this)` so you don't have to re-query the DOM. Finally, try this code but the one in the snippet I had to remove all php and ajax from it, it's just to demonstrate how you could go about it with just one handler. hope it helps

```
$('.like_button').on('click',function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
    var action = $this.data('action'); 
        event.preventDefault();
        var q = $(this).attr('data-q');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost/q/functions/l.php',
                    method: 'get',
                    data: {qi: q, a: action === 'like' ? "1":"0"},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $('#' + q + '_count').text((data.likes) + ' likes');
                        $this.data('action', action === 'like' ? 'unlike':'like'); 
                    }
                });
    });
```

```js
$('.like_button').on('click',function(event){
  var action = $(this).attr('data-action'); 
  console.log(action);
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).attr('data-action', action === 'like' ? 'unlike':'like');    
});
```

```css
a[data-action="like"]{
  background: gray;
  color: lightgray
}

a[data-action="unlike"]{
  background: blue;
  color: lightblue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="<?php echo $quote_id; ?>_count"><?php echo $likes_count; ?> likes</span>
<br>
<a class="like_button" data-q="<?php echo $quote_id; ?>" data-action="like" href="#">Like</a>
```

Comment: This works but there is an issue with this setup because unless I change `data: {qi: q, a: "1"}` to `data: {qi: q, a: "0"}` and more specifically change `a` to `1`/`0` my php function won't know whether it's a like of an unlike. Any ideas on how to change this value based on the data attribute as well?

Comment: @Ricardo, same logic as in `$this.data('action', action === 'like' ? 'unlike':'like');`. try the edit

Comment: Not just that you helped me solve this, also I've learnt something new thanks to you today.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.like_button', function(event){
    if($(this).data('action') === 'like'){
        // function for like button
    } else if ($(this).data('action') === 'unlike'){
        // function for unlike button
    }
});
```

Comment: This works for changing like to unlike but it won't go back to `like` for some reason: http://take.ms/aLdJG any ideas?

Comment: What's your function to update like/unlike value? Also instead of `$('.like_button[data-action="like"]').data('action', 'unlike');`, you can use `$('.like_button').data('action', 'unlike');`

Comment: If you use `.data('action', 'like')` method to change the data attribute, then you also have to call `.data('action')` to check the value. Because the value returned by `$(".like_button").attr("action")` won't get updated.

Comment: Thank you for your time, upvoted for the great info. Picked the other answer because it feels like the correct path.